# Django get base model from parent model

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to call parent model from base model. my model.py looks like:

models.py

```
Class A(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=350)
     description = models.TextField()

Class B(models.Model):
     reftitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     inventory = models.IntegerField()

Class C(models.Model):
      a = models.ForeignKey('A')
      b = models.ForeignKey('B')
      notes = models.TextField()
```

for some reasons I can only retrieve data from `Class A` is there any possible way I can retrieve `Class C` by reference to `Class A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all `C` from given `A`:

```
a = A()
list_of_c = a.c_set.all()
```

and get `A` from given `C`:

```
c = C()
a = c.a
```

[The reference has an own section about Many-to-one-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: thanks for you reply, can you be more specific? maybe if you can give the example with Django API reference it would be awesome!